# Jqwidgets number input to remove underscores and decimals

Tags: jquery, jqwidget

I am building a jqwidget form which has currency input fields.By default i am getting group separators,underscores and decimal places like $**,_**,__0.00.
Is it possible to remove those underscores and decimal places and have only the $ symbol?

Answer (score 1):

It has simple edit mode without "_" - see [jQWidgets Number Input](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxnumberinput/inputmode.htm?arctic)